# Jenkins sometimes runs robolecrtic tests in LEGACY resources mode

Tags: android, jenkins, robolectric

I am seeing a very strange issue where, sometimes, my android unit tests which are run using robolectric (`@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)`) run configured as LEGACY resources mode, instead of BINARY resources mode.

I am certain I have the correct code configuration:

Each module has `android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources=true`

Each module has `testOptions { unitTests { includeAndroidResources = true }}`

I am using gradle 5.6.2 and android plugin 3.5.0

The unit tests which run in LEGACY mode on jenkins fail as some required android resources are missing, hence the issue. But every time I run the same tests locally in Android Studio, theres no issue, everything always run as BINARY resources mode.
The tests which fail seem to be consistent as well.

Any ideas at all are much appreciated!

Comment: Running tests in AS is completely different beast. Can you run the same command in the terminal as you run on Jenkins?

Comment: Yes you're right it is. I can run the same git terminal commands locally that are run in Jenkins. Unfortunately I never see the error locally that I see on Jenkins 

Comment: It is not git commands, can you check gradle run?

Comment: Agh, so sorry, by git I meant gradle, my mistake.
My jenkins runs gradle testDebugUnitTest. That is the failing command. Running that same command locally, always works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be the issue we faced few weeks ago:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145162807

We faced very similar issue on gitlab setup.

Comment: WOAH! You're right, that sounds remarkably similar to what I am seeing. I will definitely give this a go and will let you know. Thank you very much for this, much appreciated!

Comment: @im_not_josh did it help ?

Comment: I have made the changes but I am not 100% if this has helped or not yet. I havent seen the same error again but there also hasnt been many builds ran since the change. It was hard to reproduce at the best of times so I will keep an eye on it.